# Desktop App Creator freezes and won't work

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying convert .exe into .appx.

I'm using Desktop App Creator, a tool offered by Microsoft.

I've followed their [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) with no problem so far, and when I execute the command to perform the conversion (in verbose mode) the program freezes at the same point every time I launch it (with no errors/exceptions/warnings before the freeze).

In the block of the verbose "Running Installer in Isolated Environment", the last verbose line shown is "Waiting for installer process to complete inside Isolated Environment".

I've left it for 2h waiting but nothing happens.

Also, the only way to stop the shell is to close the window, it seems to be unresponsive for Ctrl+C.

I would appreciate any help for this, there's nothing to be found in the program's documentation about this.

Thanks a lot in advance and regards.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution is that you need to run your installer in the isolated environment in silent mode in order to not display the wizard menu, because you cannot see the isolated environment and click the on the wizard buttons.

Add to *DesktopAppConverter -Installer* this argument:

```
-InstallerArguments /SILENT
```

Before running make sure you can install your application in silent mode by running:

```
setup.exe /SILENT
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago
replacing "/S" argument with "/quiet" in -InstallerArguments, for me worked!